# UBoot Please append a correct root boot option

Tags: embedded-linux, u-boot

I am trying to boot into an image using the following commands:

```
setenv bootcmd "load mmc 1 0x82000000 swupdate-image-imx6ull14x14evk-20230206204748.rootfs.ext4.gz.u-boot;load mmc 1 0x82a00000 imx6ull-14x14-evk.dtb;load mmc 1 0x83000000 zImage;setenv root /dev/ram0;setenv rootfstype ext4;bootz 0x83000000 - 0x82a00000"
saveenv
print bootcmd
run bootcmd
```

This starts a kernel, finds and image and attempts to run it. However my issue is

```
[    2.921973] VFS: Cannot open root device "(null)" or unknown-block(0,0): error -6
[    2.929787] Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the available partitions:
[    2.939329] 0100           65536 ram0
[    2.939338]  (driver?)
[    2.945526] 0101           65536 ram1
[    2.945531]  (driver?)
[    2.951645] 0102           65536 ram2
[    2.951649]  (driver?)
[    2.957843] 0103           65536 ram3
[    2.957847]  (driver?)
[    2.963990] 0104           65536 ram4
[    2.963995]  (driver?)
[    2.970110] 0105           65536 ram5
[    2.970114]  (driver?)
[    2.976249] 0106           65536 ram6
[    2.976254]  (driver?)
[    2.982368] 0107           65536 ram7
[    2.982372]  (driver?)
[    2.988542] 0108           65536 ram8
[    2.988547]  (driver?)
[    2.994688] 0109           65536 ram9
[    2.994692]  (driver?)
[    3.000809] 010a           65536 ram10
[    3.000814]  (driver?)
[    3.007040] 010b           65536 ram11
[    3.007045]  (driver?)
[    3.013294] 010c           65536 ram12
[    3.013298]  (driver?)
[    3.019503] 010d           65536 ram13
[    3.019508]  (driver?)
[    3.025734] 010e           65536 ram14
[    3.025739]  (driver?)
[    3.031941] 010f           65536 ram15
[    3.031946]  (driver?)
[    3.038203] 1f00           32768 mtdblock0
[    3.038208]  (driver?)
[    3.044782] b300        30558720 mmcblk1
[    3.044787]  driver: mmcblk
[    3.051596]   b301           22716 mmcblk1p1 20118f0d-01
[    3.051601]
[    3.058467]   b302          258771 mmcblk1p2 20118f0d-02
```

I cannot seem to properly set the `root=` parameter. I have tried setting it in and out of my `bootcmd`. I am not 100% of my syntax but I cannot find an example to say I am wrong. Can anyone point me to my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel command line is defined by the environment variable `bootargs`.